# Tools for splitting audio tracks

Tags: vinyl

I have a few vinyl records from which I decided to extract the content. So I bought a turntable with mp3 converter and "downloaded" all my vynils onto a a flash drive in mp3 format. However, each mp3 file now includes several tracks (i.e. all the tracks that are on the same side of the vinyl record) but instead *I want to have single files for each song*!

My question is: do you know if I can find a very simple software that allows me to split each file into separate files? I just want save the songs in the most simple way and possibly at zero cost.

My guess is that for someone using audio softwares this would be a super basic task, but not for me!  I have already tried splitmysongs.com but they ask me to subscribe to their website. I also tried veed.io but it does not work.

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: What operating system will you be installing the audio software on?  Windows?  MacOS?  Linux?  This will be the main guide to the software that you could use.

Comment: Linux. I also have Windows but it's my work laptop so I can't install software, unless it's a ready to go app that doesn't need installation but just download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several GUI programs available for editing sound files in Linux or Windows.  There are even one or two available for both.

One widely known GUI editor is [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/).  There are lots of written and video tutorials on its features and functions, and I've used it to make the kind of edits you're describing.  It's available for both Windows and Linux (and also MacOS).

Another possibility for command-line editing (probably easier to automate than a GUI) is [SoX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX), which also appears to be available for Windows as well as Linux (and Mac).  I found a blog site with a [pretty good description of SoX](https://madskjeldgaard.dk/posts/sox-tutorial-cli-tape-music/), as well as a [tutorial on exactly the track splitting you want](https://madskjeldgaard.dk/posts/sox-tutorial-split-by-silence/).  (It's amusing that the splitting tutorial uses Audacity to show the track visually)

Comment: Thanks @SottoVoce! Having a quick look at the SoX tutotial, it seems the best way to go for me. I'll try it on Linux and let you know.